# App crashes upon distribution

Tags: ios, objective-c, crash, sprite-kit, crash-reports

I have built a game using Apple's SpriteKit engine. My last version worked perfectly fine when distributing it either via Ad-Hoc or the App Store. I am now ready to distribute the next version however it crashes whenever I distribute it via Ad-Hoc. I assume this would be the same for App Store distribution. The app doesn't crash when testing it via xCode. The only external framework I've added is Facebook's Pop framework.

I have [linked the crash report](https://xcodestudent.com/stacker_crash_report) as it wouldn't fit here

Comment: Show the code from the `-[AppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] ` method.

Comment: Delete the app from device and install it via XCode and check.

Comment: Looks like a problem with `fileURLWithPath:`. @InsertWittyName is correct: post your code from `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`.

Answer (score 0):

I checked my [AppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] method and found the problem. I was creating an audio player object with a file that doesn't exist.